# Which file can be sourced in jenkins job by default?

Tags: bash, jenkins

I want to set some aliases in a node where my jenkins job runs. I tried setting it in .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile files of the user which is used to ssh to the node, but those are not picked up in the job. (It works if I manually ssh to the node, which is interactive shell and runs .bashrc by default)
Which is the correct file for setting this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems Jenkins job execute shell in standbox which not full load user environment/profile. 
You can use Jenkins `Inject environment variable` plugin to inject your aliases as environment variable which can be accessed in job's build and post-build stage.

Add a build step in job and choose `Inject environment variable` and set your aliases in Content text box or specify file path if you put aliases in source code

[image]

Job run result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I get around this without the EnvInject plugin by sourcing .bash_profile in job steps that need it, e.g.

```
. ${USER_HOME}/.bash_profile && build step command
```